# extract LastLogon from Active Directory and set it equal to lastlog.txt text box using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I have an application called user extract, as the name suggest the goal of the application is to extract every single information possible about a user by just selecting the user from the list box, the samsaccount name gets picked and is passed as a value into txtusersearcher.text text box and i am doing a `SearchUserName.PerformClick();` i have a text box created for each property and the value of the property is set equal to the text box.

Things i have tried

1)

```
 private void GetUserInformation(string username, string passowrd, string domain)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        SearchResult rs = null;
        if (txtSearchUser.Text.Trim().IndexOf("@") > 0)
            rs = SearchUserByEmail(GetDirectorySearcher(username, passowrd, domain), txtSearchUser.Text.Trim());
        else
            rs = SearchUserByUserName(GetDirectorySearcher(username, passowrd, domain), txtSearchUser.Text.Trim());

        if (rs != null)
        {
            showuserinfo();
             ShowUserInformation(rs);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User not found!!!", "Search Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

`private void ShowUserInformation(SearchResult rs)
        {if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogon"].Value != null)
             lastlog.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogon"].Value.ToString();`

2)

```
   if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogon"].Value != null)
          lastlog.Text = (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogon"].Value.ToString());
           int  x; 
                x =  Int32.Parse(lastlog.Text);
               lastlog.Text = x.ToString();
```

3)  I read online that using principal context, userprincipal, and principal searcher does the trick and tried this

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        UserPrincipal qbeuser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
        PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeuser);
        foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
        {
            UserPrincipal founduser = found as UserPrincipal;
            {
                if (founduser.LastLogon != null)
                    lastlog.Text = founduser.LastLogon.ToString();

            }
        }
```

This works but this brings in the lastlogon of the first user in the list box, i want this value to change when each user is clicked. I know the main reason is that the lastlogon value is stored as a integer8 where as the others are strings. when you use value.tostring(); it doesn't work and i get `System.__ComObject` error. People suggested using cast, but i am new to this technology a sample casting code would be much appreciated and a workaround to this issue will be much much appreciated Thank You Guys!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @DJKRAZE if your wondering this questions is actually the same as the one i was asking before, i thought the problem was fixed little did i know that if was only returning the lastLogon time for the first user in the listbox, for any user that was selected the text box had the same value, so any suggestions on how i can make the text in the lastlog textbox change for each user.

Answer (score 2):

To get lastLogon value as a readable date time attribute you need to convert it from 'ComObject' to long type firstly, and then convert this long value to DateTime:

```
 DirectoryEntry de = New DirectoryEntry(ldap, logon, password) // get user as DirectoryEntry object
 object adsLargeInteger = de.Properties["lastLogon"].Value;
 if (adsLargeInteger == null)
 {
   // todo 
 }
 long highPart =
            (Int32)
                adsLargeInteger.GetType()
                    .InvokeMember("HighPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, adsLargeInteger, null);
 long lowPart =
            (Int32)
                adsLargeInteger.GetType()
                    .InvokeMember("LowPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, adsLargeInteger, null);
 long lastLogonL = (long)((uint)lowPart + (((long)highPart) << 32)); // Get value as long
 DateTime lastLogonStr = DateTime.FromFileTime(lastLogonL); // get value as DateTime string
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can get information from the AD when clicking the username. I am suggesting the last method but by searching for a specific user with user name.

```
private void UpdateLastLogonField(string userName)
{
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    UserPrincipal qbeuser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);
    if (qbeuser != null && qbeuser.lastlogon != null)
    {
        lastlog.Text = qbeuser.LastLogon.ToString();
    } else {
        lastLog.Text = "Could not get last logon info";
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If read from DirectoryEntry, e.g. "rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogon"].Value", LastLogon attribute is a COM object that can be cast to an IADsLargeInteger.

But if read directly from SearchResult, e.g. "rs.Properties["lastLogon"][0]", LastLogon attribute is a Integer8. This assume "lastLogon" is added to PropertiesToLoad in the DirectorySearcher.

But please note that LastLogon only record the last log-on time on the DC and is not replicated.
i.e. user log-on using DC2, value of LastLogon on DC1 is not updated.